# Mongoose bulk insert or update documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a node.js app, and I've been searching for a way around using the Model.save() function because I will want to save many documents at the same time, so it would be a waste of network and processing doing it one by one.

I found a way to bulk insert. However, my model has two properties that makes them unique, an ID and a HASH (I am getting this info from an API, so I believe I need these two informations to make a document unique), so, I wanted that if I get an already existing object it would be updated instead of inserted into the schema.

Is there any way to do that? I was reading something about making concurrent calls to save the objects, using Q, however I still think this would generate an unwanted load on the Mongo server, wouldn't it? Does Mongo or Mongoose have a method to bulk insert or update like it does with insert?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [`Bulk.find(<query>).upsert().update(<update>)`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/#Bulk.find.upsert) function.

You can use it this way:

```
bulk = db.yourCollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
for (<your for statement>) {
    bulk.find({ID: <your id>, HASH: <your hash>}).upsert().update({<your update fields>});
}
bulk.execute(<your callback>)
```

For each document, it will look for a document matching the `{ID: <your id>, HASH: {your hash}}` criteria. Then:

- If it finds one, it will update that document using `{<your update fields>}`
- Otherwise, it will create a new document

As you need, it will not make a connection to the mongo server on each iteration of the `for` loop. Instead a single call will be made on the `bulk.execute()` line.

Comment: will test this out in a moment. thanks a lot! it seems this will do exactly what I want.

Comment: thanks, it worked almost like a charm. I confirm its inserting or updating into the database, however, right after the bulk.execute finishes I get an error and my server crashes. Could you take a look to see if you know whats going on? Here is the error message: http://pastebin.com/SgYe4b3X

Comment: figured it out. was missing a callback for the execute call. bulk.execute(callback) solved it, callback being a function

Comment: thank you too, I have updated the answer according your comment.

Comment: Apparently `.insertMany` is the way to go now? https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3122#issuecomment-117232568 But, I haven't found a good way to handle updates to documents with unique keys